# Spring application not taking spring.schemas into account

Tags: java, spring, xsd, classpath, spring-boot

I have a Spring batch that uses spring-boot 0.5.0M2. I use the assembly jar-with-dependencies to generate an executable JAR file. I have checked that the JAR is generated with the proper dependencies, i.e. that all required Sprinf xsds are located where they should be, and that the spring-boot plugin has generated a proper META-INF/spring.schemas.

I run my app from a Cygwin terminal, but due to the NTLM authentication my proxy requires, I have no network access from the Cygwin shell.

If I run my app with mvn spring-boot:run it works. However in production the batch will be ran with java -jar myExecutableJar.jar and I am pretty certain that the server will not have access to Internet.

In this case I get the following error:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::

2013-12-12 17:15:42,197 INFO [fr.foo.my.app.MyBatch] - <Starting MyBatch on UC401711VW7JAV1 with PID 6848 (C:\nicolas\git\foobatch\target\indexer-batch-0.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar started by S818203)>
2013-12-12 17:16:03,481 WARN [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - <Ignored XML validation warning>
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 12; schema_reference.4 : Echec de la lecture du document de sch▒ma 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd' pour les raisons suivantes : 1) Le document est introuvable ; 2) Le document n'a pas pu ▒tre lu ; 3) L'▒l▒ment racine du document n'est pas <xsd:schema>.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
[...]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at [...]
```

So I interpret this as the app trying to download spring-beans-3.2 XSD instead of taking into account spring.schemas and use the classpath resource that is present in the JAR.

Is there a way to force the Spring context to do this?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Could be a bug, I suppose, but it works for me (build a jar, unplug network cable, run jar). It seems more likely to me that you don't actually have the `spring.schemas` on your classpath somehow. Not sure how that could happen, but check the contents of your jar.

Comment: P.S. you really need to upgrade Spring Boot. A lot happened to the project since M2. Do you get the same problem with a snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this error is using explicit versioned schema URLs in XML, and then accidentally inclusding an *older* version of the relevant JAR in your classpath. E.g. if you refer to `spring-beans-4.0.xsd` in an XML header but include `spring-context:3.2.*` in your transitive dependencies.